# Why doesn't a for (...in...) loop return the key when iterating through an object method

Tags: javascript

Why is it that when I run employee.report() on this object method I get alerts for "Undefined is John Smith", etc.

```
var employee = {
    name: "John Smith",
    job: "Programmer",
    age: 31,
    report: function() {
        for (k in employee) {
            alert(this.k + " is " + employee[k])
        }
    }
}
```

but when I run the loop the console like this

```
for (k in employee) {
    alert(this.k + " is " + employee[k])
}
```

it returns the proper alerts ("name is John Smith", etc.)

Comment: It should be `this[k]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `k` you should use `k` instead of `this.k`. so replace `alert(this.k+ " is " +employee[k])` with `alert(k+ " is " +employee[k])` then your code will work successfully.

References for understand this in js.

1. [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp)
2. [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
3. [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/this-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't defined `employee` in the scope of the `employee` variable, you must use the keyword `this` to reference the object itself.

```js
var employee = {
  name: "John Smith",
  job: "Programmer",
  age: 31,
  report: function(){
      for (k in this){
          alert(k+ " is " +this[k])
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The usage of `employee` in the `report` method is problematic, but it's not the cause of OP's issue.

Comment: Can confirm this wasn't the issue, but good to know nonetheless, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the `report` function `this` is the `employee` object, which doesn't have a `k` property. So `this.k` is `undefined`. If you want to print the property name, just use `k`:

```
alert(k + " is " + employee[k]);
```

Outside the function, `this` is the global `window` object. Global variables are automatically made properties of `window`, so `this.k` is the same as `k`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why the report function doesn't work.

Comment: I explained that in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar explain very well, I just add more detail

In your object method `report`

`this` in `this.k` points to `employee` object
and you get `Undefined` because `employee` does not have a property named `k`.
You should use `this[k]` instead.

And in te loop outside of object

```js
for (k in employee){
  alert(this.k+ " is " +employee[k])
}
```

`this` in `this.k` points to global `Window` object
Your code actually is

```js
for (var k in employee){
  alert(this.k+ " is " +employee[k])
}
```

`k` will become a global variable. `this.k` is same as `window.k` or `k`

BTW: You should use const/let and `use strict` for more clarify your variable